# Display String data in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

```
String Person_Name=et1.getText().toString();
String Mobile_Number=et2.getText().toString();
String Person_Query=et3.getText().toString();
String Action=et4.getText().toString();
```

This data should be displayed in `ListView` to another Activity. How it could be done?

Comment: you pass all the values in bundle by putting all the values in ArrayList of String. But i guess for this only 4 values why are you using listview ? There is no need of `ListView` you can use the `TextView` in next activity and show all the values there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String Person_Name=et1.getText().toString();
String Mobile_Number=et2.getText().toString();
String Person_Query=et3.getText().toString();
String Action=et4.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(activity_context , second.class);
String[] s = {Person_Name,Mobile_Number,Person_Query,Action};
intent.putExtra("INFO", s);
```

**On second activity :** get value from intent

```
Intent i = Your_Context.getIntent();
String[] s1 = i.getStringArrayExtra("INFO");
```

you can set this array to your ListView.

Hope it will help you.